# ¿Cómo podria solucionar este error en android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto me manda este error y ya he intentado desinstalarlo y no logro solucionarlo

Aquí esta el build.gradle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega tu build.gradle por favor.

Comment: Podrías escribir el error para ayudarte a buscar una solución, me refiero que lo escribas para copiar y pegar, que quizás creo saber que pueda ser.

Comment: ya coloque en los comentarios el build

Comment: @FernandoCarranza cual es el paquete de tu aplicación?

Comment: @Elenasys disculpa mi ignorancia pero a que te refieres?

Comment: @FernandoCarranza es com.example.fernando.myapplication y es similar a tu estructura de folders? no la cambiaste de casualidad?

Comment: Creo que a lo que esta en la otra imagen que coloque te referia no

Answer (score 0):

Realmente creo que el error te lo está dando en esta línea:

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Realmente la versión del SDK que estás especificando todavía no existe (la máxima actual es la 24) por lo que creo que es el motivo por el que te lanza el error.

Puedes ver todos los números de versión del SDK **[aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es)**.

Por consiguiente, también tendrías errónea esta línea:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: en el dado caso que yo seleccione la numero 19 siempre tengo que poner 24 o es dependiendo?

Comment: @FernandoCarranza Es dependiendo de las especificaciones que tu quieras para tu aplicación. Si quieres que tenga soporte para la 24, entonces tendrás que indicar la 24. El `targetSdkVersion` lo puedes suprimir para que no haya un límite de versión y soporte a todas las versiones a partir de la 19. Yo te recomiendo poner siempre la máxima versión para que puedas soportar una mayor gama de dispositivos.

Comment: @Error404 ya existe 25 :P de hecho el SDKTools ya tiene versión 25.2.2